# Скачивание документа от пользователя vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Я пишу бота в ВК, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда пользователь отправлял боту документ, бот скачивал бы себе этот документ (не в группу загружал, а именно скачивал его).
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Элементы запроса `messages.getHistory` содержат ключ `attachments`, в котором перечисляются все прикрепленные к сообщению документы. Каждый из них в свою очередь имеет ключ `url`, по которому этот документ можно скачать через `requests.get()`.

Посмотрите на структуру в [примере запроса](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory).